# Stripe, checking if coupon exists before creating subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to check to see if a coupon exists before creating a subscription. It basically allows me to capture the card info without charging the card until the end of the trial period.

If it exists, I don't want to create it. If it doesnt, it needs to be created.

However, it keeps throwing an error when I try this:

```
// Check if coupon is valid
$coupon_check = \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve('free-period');

if (!$coupon_check->valid) {
  $coupon = \Stripe\Coupon::create(array(
    'duration' => 'once',
    'id' => 'free-period',
    'percent_off' => 100,
  ));
}
```

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: Somehow it throws an error for "token already used".  When I remove the code and just create the coupon manually, everything works fine. I wonder if I need to call this check in a separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after playing with this for a bit, I have found the correct solution. For whatever reason, if statements don't seem to work with the Stripe API too well.  So instead we use `try` and `catch`.

```
try {
    \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve('free-period');
  } catch(\Exception $e) {
    \Stripe\Coupon::create(array(
      'percent_off' => 100,
      'duration' => 'once',
      'id' => 'free-period'
      )
    );
  }
```